# Black Holed Request Cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, cakephp

On my index page I have check boxes in each row of my table.

To edit selected items, I use javascript/jquery to grab the class of the checkboxes, build an array of the ids and then post it to the edit selected method in my controller.

Now, this all works perfectly, but when Security in enabled in my App Controller, my post gets black holed and the array is not posted.

Here is my index.ctp file:

```
<table id="indexTable">
    <thead><tr>
        <th> <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('select_all', array('value' => 'select_all')); ?> </th>
        <th> <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id', 'ID'); ?> </th>
        <th> <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name', 'Name'); ?> </th>
        <th>Auto Offset  </th>  <th>UTC Offset Sec  </th>  <th>In Month  </th>
        <th>In Week      </th>  <th>In Dow          </th>  <th>In Hour   </th>  <th>Out Month   </th>
        <th>Out Week     </th>  <th>Out Dow         </th>  <th>Out Hour  </th>  <th>Offset Sec  </th>
        <th>DST Ref      </th>  <th>Actions      </th>
    </tr></thead>

    <tbody>

<?php
$this->Form->create('LocalClock');
foreach($localClocks as $LocalClock) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>  <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('LocalClocks'.$LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'], array('value' => $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'], 'hiddenField' => false));?>  </td>
            <td>  <?php echo $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id']; ?>              </td>
            <td>  <?php echo $LocalClock['LocalClock']['name']; ?>            </td>
            <td>  <?php echo $LocalClock['LocalClock']['auto_offset']; ?>     </td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>

<!-- This <div> contains all the actions that can be performed on the Local Clocks. -->
<div>
    <p>

        <span style="float: left">
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit All Items'), array('action' => 'editAll'), array('class' => 'link'));?> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span>

        <span style="float: left">
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit Selected Items'), array('action' => 'lceditSelected'), array('class' => 'general_dialog'));?> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span>

        <span style="float: right">
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Delete Selected Items'), array('action' => 'deleteSelected'), array('class' => 'general_dialog'));?> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span>
    <?php $this->Form->end(); ?>

    </p>
</div>
```

I took out some unimportant stuff.  The problem is with my edit selected and delete selected functions.

Here is the javascript code that waits for their click and then builds the array to post to the controller action:

```
$('.general_dialog').live('click', function()
{
    $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });

        var $selDialog = $("#general_dialog").dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
        });

        var postInfo = $('#LocalClockIndexForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: "post",
        data: postInfo,
        success: function (response)
        {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("failed");
        }
    });
        $selDialog.load($(this).attr('href'), function ()
        {
            $selDialog.dialog('open');
        });
    return false; // Ensure the controller does not redirect to the actual edit page
});
```

Any help on how to get it to work without getting black holed would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

------------------------------------------EDIT----------------------------------------------
I added `$this->Form->create('LocalClock')` and `$this->Form->end()` to the table and I switched the $.post() to and $.ajax() call.

If I send the serialised form, I don't get a black hole, but when I look at the data posted, it does not include any of the check box ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example lacks form tags.

You need to create and end the form with the Form helper to ensure that the security token is included in the form generation:

```
$this->Form->create();
  // Other form elements here.
$this->Form->end();
```

Comment: I tried putting in the `form->create()` right above the foreach loop line and the `form->end()` right after the div containing the edit/delete selected buttons but I am still getting black holed. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I might know what the problem is, I include the `form->create` and `form->end` code, but my button to post the data does not grab that security information.

Comment: I found out that that my problem was i had multiple forms inside my big form. I removed these and everything works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to modify crsf protection policy?
If you reload the page with the same token, the Security component will black hole the request.

```
var $components = array('Security'=>array('csrfUseOnce'=>false));
```

Comment: I did look into using this, but I ended up changing the way I submitted the forms. Thanks